# Google String Code

Tags: php, forms, code-snippets

I'm developing a small scale website, and the client has just informed me that there are code snippets that can be used, via a contact form. Basically, a contact form will be used, then once the submission has been made, a code snippet that is placed in the thank you page, would submit the information from the form to Analytics.

I've had a look but I just can't seem to find the right snippet, has anyone used this before.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found an answer, the information can be found at AdWords central via Google.

www.google.co.uk/AdWords

Comment: a direct link to the solution would be nice for other users having the same problem.

Comment: Well seeing as this is as far as the link will allow you to go withou signing in I thought the link would be pointless, but I've put one up.